# How to write a binary literal in Dart

Tags: dart, numbers, literals

How do you write a Binary Literal in Dart?

I can write a Hex Literal like so:

```
Int Number = 0xc
```

If I try the conventional way to write a Binary Literal:

```
Int Number = 0b1100
```

I get an error. I've tried to look it up, but I've not been able to find any information other than for hex.

Comment: It's not supported in dart. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/581)

Answer (score 10):

There are currently no built-in binary number literals in Dart (or any base other than 10 and 16).

The closest you can get is: `var number = int.parse("1100", radix: 2);`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use this:

```dart
// 0b1100 -> 1 at 3th bit and 1 at 2nd bit
final number = 1 << 3 | 1 << 2;

// Print binary string
print(number.toRadixString(2)) // 1100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binary package:

```dart
import 'package:binary/binary.dart';

void main() {
  // New API.S
  print(0x0C.toBinaryPadded(8)); // 00001100
}
```

see: https://pub.dev/documentation/binary/latest/